# Get information from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

How could I get the information after my main url with php?

Like let's say I have a url like this:

`http://www.myawesomedomain.com/about`

How could I pull the `about` part of that url out and use it in php?

I know you can use the `$_GET[]` variable for url but I don't want to mess up the url. What is a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: It depends on your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I can edit the .htaccess file. I have created one just to allow php in .html pages. What would I need to do in that file?

Comment: Use a CMS (like WordPress), framework (like Slim) or do it yourself using .htaccess/url rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- step 1) get the REQUEST URI from the _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  $url = _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
- step 2) parse the url with parse_url; this gives you an associative array with a path key:
  i.e. $parsed_url = parse_url($url);$path = $parsed_url['path'];
- step 3) and this could be easy or hard. easy is to get the last component of the path. using preg_match. e.g.preg_match('//(.+)$/', $path, &$matches);
- step 4) $matches returns an array that returns the entire match, plus the captured match. that is what you put in parentheses. you only have one captured match which is $matches[1];
- step 5) you are done. $about = $matches[1];

learn more about preg_match here: https://www.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will contain the full URI. You can extract the bits you care about with a regular expression or [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The request url might include a query string. The easiest way to parse out just the path is to use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
echo parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
// prints "/about"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called Url Rewrite and can follow this guide to learn more.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

If you look on the Internet, there are many examples.